# python pact verifier is not retrieving pacts from the broker

Tags: python, pact, contract

I have a pact published to pact broker

[Pact Broker 2.89.0] https://i.stack.imgur.com/Domku.png

When I am trying to run pact verifier, it says no pacts found. Here is the code snippet

```
    verifier = Verifier(provider='',
                        provider_base_url=PACT_BASE_URL,
                        provider_app_version='latest')

    default_opts = { 'pact_url':'https://test.pactflow.io/pacts/provider/{Provider}/consumer/{Consumer}/latest',
        'broker_url':'https://test.pactflow.io/' ,
        'broker_base_url': 'https://test.pactflow.io/',
        'provider_base_url':'http://localhost:5000',
        'broker_token':'',
        'consumer_version_selectors':["latest": True}],
        'publish-version':'2.0.0',
        'publish_verification_results':True,
        'provider_app_version':'latest',
        'provider':''}
    output, logs = verifier.verify_with_broker(**default_opts,include_wip_pacts_since='2021-01-01')
    assert (output == 0)
```

Running pact verifier is saying
WARN: No pacts were found for the consumer versions selected
INFO: Fetching pacts for '' from https://test.pactflow.io/ with the selection criteria: latest for tag, work in progress pacts created after 2021-01-01

I am using starter Pact Broker Version: 2.89.0

Please suggest !

Answer (score 0):

Unless I'm mistaken, you haven't specified the name of the provider so it doesn't know how to discover pacts for the current provider.

The provider app version is also not a version, it's the string `latest`. It should be something like a git sha. See the [best practice guide](https://docs.pact.io/getting_started/versioning_in_the_pact_broker/#best-practices).

Your selectors are also invalid, you'll need at least a tag if you go with `latest` see [the docs](https://docs.pact.io/pact_broker/advanced_topics/consumer_version_selectors/) for more.